# MasterPage session value issue. c#

Tags: c#, session, master-pages

I am trying to set the value of the "MasterPageFile" property to the value of a session variable.

here is what I have now:

```
MasterPageFile = Session["selectedLayout"];
```

keeps saying this error:

'System.Web.UI.Page.Session' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'

also tried

```
MasterPageFile = Session["selectedLayout"].ToString();
```

but have been getting this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That code should not produce that error. Are you sure that's the right code that's causing the error?

Comment: Yea I am trying to override the Page_Preinit function inside my Default.aspx.cs file. The _default class inherets from the Page class.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this check:

```
if (Session["selectedLayout"] != null)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question here but is MasterPageFile being instantiated anywhere in your page? I ask because if that was the first place you referenced and started using MasterPageFile and it is out of scope you would get that type of error, just a shot in the dark here.

Comment: Yea, here is what I have at the top of my Default.aspx <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/LayoutOne.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Title="Reviews" %>

Comment: Right, do this instead this.MasterPageFile = "MyTestDesign.master" and see if that works. If that does in fact change the page layout in the preinit then we are just dealing with a casting issue. You can attempt (String)Session["Whatever"] and see if that does the trick. Also you can try break pointing at that object and seeing if there is anything in it. You may need to check if anything is in it first and if not load in a default, good luck.